# How to decode %3F to '?' and %3D to '=' in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7, redirect, urldecode

I am getting this url redirection from third party site
http://localhost:4200/account/congratulations%3FdocumentId%3Dnnn

but i need to decode as 
http://localhost:4200/account/congratulations?documentId=nnn

for rendering my page
'%3F' = '?'
'%3D' = '='
where do i need to decode this in my project?

Comment: how do you get `http://localhost:4200/account/congratulations%3FdocumentId%3Dnnn` ?

Comment: i get this link from other site... actually this link is redirectin to my site from third party site

Comment: Where do you get this data from? Is it typed in by a user on a form? Is it a response from an http request you've executed on a service?  Update your question with these kinds of details. Also, this URL you have only seems to be partially encoded (/ aren't encoded) which is also strange.

Comment: It's not your app's fault. It is considered a broken link from another site

Comment: but i have to decode this url. from my app... pls suggest how to decode or url rewrite

Comment: @Dennis i just updated my question... pls check

Comment: If you can't make the third party site create a proper link, you'll have to create a new route in your application to be able to listen on that weird URL, extract information from the URL and then rebuild the URL properly and redirect your user to that new location.

Comment: Usually, a redirected url will be decoded by the browser itself. either your decoded url is not as per the standards.

Comment: @Dennis i can't make third party site to change url, how can i decode this url as proper link from our side

Comment: You can't decode it because that link is basically broken. If you want to solve it in your application you could use the approach I mentioned. But the best way is for that third party site to properly redirect to your site

Answer (score 2):

You can use decodeURIComponent

Example :

```
decodeURIComponent("%3d")
```

Comment: where should i need to add this method?

Answer (score 1):

> You can use decodeURI method in your service (the place where you're fetching that url )

```
decodeURI(url)
```

Comment: i am not fetching that url... it's redirecting from other site after some operation completion in that third party site